# attempting to call a function that clicks a hidden button from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a code in jquery that hides a button and at the same time click the button when the function of the code block is called. this is the snippet of the code

```
var successBtn = $("#sucessBtn"); //declare the button
function successConfirm(){

    // Hide the button
    successBtn.hide();

    successBtn.on("click", function() {
        alert("in onclick");
        successBtn.click();
    });
}
```

I am attempting to call the function in javascript block as shown

```
onClose: function(){
          successConfirm();
          alert('window closed');
      }
```

the alert in the block is executed but the alert in clicking the butting dynamically never gets executed. Please what could be wrong

Comment: try `successBtn[0].click();` instead of `successConfirm` since `successConfirm` only attaches the event and doesn't invoke the event

Comment: You are trying to attach on click event on successBtn and not triggering on click . You can attach even outside successConfirma function and trigger click using $().trigger("click");

Comment: please why was this question downvoted. where has the question gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`successConfirm` hooks up an event handler, it doesn't actually click the button. It also sets up an endless loop by triggering a click in response to a click, which...would be bad.

If you want it to click the button, have it do that rather than (or in addition to) hooking up an event handler:

```
function successConfirm(){

    // Hide the button
    successBtn.hide();

    successBtn.on("click", function() {
        alert("in onclick");
    });

    successBtn.click(); // <=== Moved this
}
```

Note that the above will add a new click handler every time. You probably want to separate those two things, probably put the `on` call *outside* `successConfirm`, somewhere in your setup code.

---

In a comment you've said:

> I have moved it but button is not clicked

This suggests to me that the button doesn't exist as of when you do `var successBtn = $("#sucessBtn");`. Perhaps you're doing that too early. There's really no particularly good reason to do it in advance, just do it in `successConfirm`:

```
function successConfirm(){
    $("#successBtn")
        .hide()
        .on("click", function() {
            alert("in onclick");
        })
        .click();
}
```

Comment: I have moved it but button is not clicked

Comment: @parker: That suggests to me the button doesn't exist yet when you're doing `var successBtn = $("#sucessBtn");`. See edit at end of answer.

Comment: on loading the page the button does not hide but the click function is responding to event dynamically. how can the button be hidden permanently

Comment: @parker as I said in my answer you need to place `successBtn.hide();`  outside of `successConfirm` function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you trigger the click inside the `onClick` event ... so the click waits for the click (you get me ...)

What you could do is :

```
successBtn.on("click", function() {
    alert("in onclick");
});
 successBtn.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

A call to **.trigger()** executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user:

```
successBtn.trigger('click');

successBtn.on("click", function() {
    alert("in onclick");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You are doing a whole mess here, by triggering the click event while you are attaching it in this code:

```
successBtn.on("click", function() {
    alert("in onclick");
    successBtn.click(); //This is misplaced here
});
```

And why you are attaching the `click` event to your button, inside the `successConfirm` function, it should be better placed outside of it.

**Solution:**

I have updated your code so it makes sense now:

```
var successBtn = $("#sucessBtn"); //declare the button

//Attach the click event 
successBtn.on("click", function() {
  alert("in onclick");
});


function successConfirm() {

  // Hide the button
  successBtn.hide();

  //click the button
  successBtn.click();
}
```

**Note:**

You better hide the button in the beggining by moving `successBtn.hide();` outside the `successConfirm` function, so it would be hidden before and without calling `successConfirm()`.